# Is it possible to replace the functionality of Kafka with a data lake or normal database like mongodb?

Tags: database, apache-kafka, data-lake

As a junior data engineer I am looking to understand exactly why we need Kafka. I am assuming that Kafka is a message queuing program that acts as a broker between data producing and consuming systems. So why can't we just use a normal database or data lake as a central storage and let that act as a broker between systems?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a generic question, most of the Software Engineers do have, but this can't be answered in a few lines with 100% justification why we can opt for KAFKA as integration platform.

Each and every technology/technical entity will be having its own advantages/disadvantages and most of the modern technologies such as KAFKA was introduced just to mitigate some of the issues we have been having with organization, especially in a data driven organization.

There are thousands of article out there to understand 'Why KAFKA', and you can read more here https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/

Since your debate is between relational DB and KAFKA, you better have a glance on [https://aiven.io/blog/apache-kafka-and-the-great-database-debate#:~:text=What%20does%20Apache%20Kafka%20do,of%20events%20as%20they%20unfold](https://aiven.io/blog/apache-kafka-and-the-great-database-debate#:%7E:text=What%20does%20Apache%20Kafka%20do,of%20events%20as%20they%20unfold).

On a nutshell:

**Apache KAFKA is a distributed streaming platform. What does that mean?**

- Distributed Systems
- Distributed computing is a field of computer science that studies distributed systems.
- A distributed system is a system whose components are located on different networked computers, which communicate and coordinate their actions by passing messages to one another.
  The components interact with one another in order to achieve a common goal.

**A streaming application has three key capabilities**

- Publish and Subscribe streams of records like message queue or EMS
- Store streams of records in a fault-tolerant durable way.
- Process streams of records as they occur.

**Used for two broad classes of applications**

- Building real-time streaming pipeline to get data reliably between system and process
- Building real-time streaming applications that transforms or react to streams of data.

**Key concepts**

- Runs as a cluster of one or more server that spans across multiple data centers.
- KAFKA cluster stores streams of records in a category called topic.
- Each records consists of a key, value and a timestamp.

Comment: You can mark this as a correct answer, if it is helpful to you, so other can use this as a reference.